# Could multiple transmitters on the same frequency work if phase-locked to GPS? (gedanken)

Tags: gps, transmitter, interference

I've been noodling this concept for a while; it seems to me that if it were actually workable somebody would be doing it already, but I haven't heard of it happening.  So where do I go off the rails here?

---

If two transmitters operate on the same frequency, a receiver will generally get audio that is annoying-to-unusable.  This is due to heterodyning between the RF oscillators and between the differing program material (modulation).

But what if the transmitters were phase-locked to a common standard?  Now the RF oscillators would be identical in frequency and phase.  If the modulation came from a digital file with a timecode, it could also be perfectly synced to the same standard, and then the transmitters would not interfere.  The synchronization standard could be GPS receivers.

Is GPS accurate enough to pull this off in, say, the AM broadcast band?

I'm thinking this might be useful for e.g. a "pirate" radio broadcast that doesn't run afoul of FCC regulations (albeit not addressing copyright issues :- ).  It would also be difficult to locate the transmitters, if they were camouflaged or hidden.  The transmitters could be done pretty cheaply and you can fit a lot of audio on a cheap SD card.

Comment: I think you've just invented Single Frequency Networks, which do exactly that. Not to hide the transmitters, but to save frequencies (you can cover a whole mid-sized country with DVB-T2 using SFN). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-frequency_network

Comment: *If two transmitters operate on the same frequency, a receiver will generally get audio that is annoying-to-unusable.* You're making assumptions on what is used to transmit this audio that you don't mention. And also, as Paul mentions, which haven't been true. And as I might add – which haven't been true for consumer devices since the mid-to-late 1990s, so nearly 30 years.

Comment: It sounds like your idea is to broadcast two or more different audio signals on one RF channel.  That's not going to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. The physics work how you think they do - the radio signals just add up. In fact you don't necessarily need GPS as (I think) you could use the radio waves themselves for synchronization.

*However*, the receiver will still see a different propagation delay from each transmitter, causing them to receive multiple copies of the signal slightly out of phase. How slightly? Depends on the frequency and position. If the receiver is halfway in between two transmitters transmitting identical signals, they receive both signals in-phase with constructive interference. If they move a quarter wavelength towards either transmitter, now they have destructive interference and the signal is very weak.

If the receiver is next to one transmitter, they'll receive the signal from the nearby transmitter, plus a delayed signal from the distant one. If you transmit AM audio it will sound like an echo. If you transmit analog video it will look like "ghosting".

You need a modulation scheme which can tolerate these "echoes". Some can, such as OFDM. In fact, this is how digital TV and radio is modulated in Europe, and they can use the same frequency for multiple transmitters because of it. I suspect they generate the analog signal once and send it to each transmitter (e.g. via microwave), but *with enough engineering work and a way to synchronize* there's no reason you couldn't generate the same signal independently at each transmitter.

Comment: It even works with analog FM. When one signal is significantly stronger than the other, the receiver will tend to "capture" on the stronger signal. It's only in the areas where the overlapping signals are approximately equal that you have to worry about synchronizing the modulation (but not the carriers). Many years ago I designed such a "simulcasting" system for commercial FM broadcasting in large metropolitan areas -- and yes, it is GPS-based.

Comment: I'm thinking of transmit power of 100mW or less, in a small package with not much of an antenna.  So the transmitters would have to be spaced only a hundred feet or so apart to cover an area.  This is well under 1/4 wavelength at the bottom of the broadcast AM band (540KHz).

Comment: @CrashGordon I don't know about the USA, but in New Zealand there are "licence-free bands" (not the technical name) available for transmitters meeting certain rules, and "low-power FM" transmitters can also be operated without a licence (however you are not allowed to operate more than one LPFM transmitter transmitting the same program). You should see if the USA has similar rules. You may be able to legally operate your network without requesting a licence. And then there's amateur radio, of course. I hear it's not difficult to get a ham licence.

Answer (score 1):

You mention "pirate transmitters" that won't "run afoul of the FCC." That sounds to me like you want to transmit your own audio on the same frequency as an existing transmitter without causing interference.

That will **not** work.  If your transmitter is on exactly the same frequency as an existing radio station, then you will cause interference - you will "run afoul of the FCC."  Your transmitter will block reception of the licensed transmitter - that's interference, and will get you in trouble.

If there were no interference at the radio frequency level, then it still wouldn't help your pirate radio station. If you receive two signals at the same time with the same transmitter frequency on an AM radio, the audio will be mixed.  Listeners would hear your pirate music and the licensed broadcast at the same time - they are normally only separable by the different frequencies of the carrier.

Your undetectable pirate radio transmitter can't work, no matter how well you synchronize it to an existing station.

---

The other answers seem to be concentrating on the legitmate uses of multiple transmitters on a single frequency rather than your concept of an "uncatchable pirate transmitter."

Legitimate uses include licensed operators using licensed, synchronized transmitters to cover a larger (licensed) area using lower power transmitters.  In all such cases, all the transmitters are transmitting the same content on a single frequency.

I know of one system that a police organisation used to extend coverage over a major highway network.  There were many transmitters spaced long the major roads to make sure they had complete coverage.

All of the transmitters sent the same content.  The transmitters all used the same radio channel, and hence (almost) exactly the same frequency.  That "almost" is important.

If the transmitters had been on exactly the same frequency, there would have been dead spots where the signal from one transmitter exactly canceled out the signal from a neighboring transmitter. That kind of cancellation is no surprise - it works just like [this demonstration of cancellation using speakers and sound.](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/experiments/chpt-4/sound-cancellation/)

The solution was to have all the transmitters tuned to within a few hertz of one another while making sure that no two transmitters used exactly the same frequency.  The signals could cancel each other out but there were no standing dead zones.  The received signal strength would wobble a bit due to the signals from the transmitters having constructive and destructive interference, but that didn't bother things.

Comment: "Pirate radio" as I called it, was referring to an unlicensed station operating in a licensed band.  Rather than trying to stomp on a legitimate station, they look for an empty slot and "homestead" it.  These stations usually operate at power levels that cover a small town or perhaps a college campus.  This puts them well above "unlicensed" power levels. and that's when the FCC gets involved.  The distributed transmitter concept would allow for low-power, "FCC-safe" transmitters.

Answer (score 0):

WWVB uses two antennas (called "North" and "South") at \$f_C=60 kHz.\$
Wavelength 5000 m. Antenna separation is 857 m.
For sure, they are synchronized from a primary standard, not GPS.
[Transmitted pattern](https://tf.nist.gov/stations/wwvbcoverage.htm) at various time-of-day is calculated, one of which (0600 UTC) is shown here:
[image: WWVB transmitted geographic coverage 0600 UTC]
Perhaps the herringbone pattern is a result of phasing of those two antennas? Receivers in a trough might be getting destructive interference from each antenna, while a receiving site at a peak might be getting constructive interference from each antenna.
Or possibly ionospheric reflections/refractions are the source of peaks/troughs, since these differ at various hours of the day.